# Embedding Euclidean buildings into products of trees

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, trees, buildings, embeddings, metric-embeddings

A Euclidean building has a natural metric space structure. (A definition of Euclidean building can be found on Wikipedia, or, more expansively, in Section 4 of [Kleiner-Leeb](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.nyu.edu%2F~bkleiner%2Fsymm.pdf&ei=6Ne2VI-5O4GPgwSi4oDoBQ&usg=AFQjCNFa3zbDknDrMBUgHJsBY9ObDYl7pA&sig2=ux5QribcDgJZMyQA3uWbfA&bvm=bv.83640239,d.eXY).)

Question: Is it true that every (finite rank) Euclidean building has a biLipschitz embedding into a finite product of metric $\mathbb{R}$-trees?

It follows from the results of [Lang-Schlichenmaier](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410048) that a Euclidean building $X$ of rank $n$ admits an embedding $f$ into the product $T$ of $n+1$ trees, with the property that for some $C>1$ and $p>0$,
$$ C^{-1}d_X(x,y)^p \leq d_T(f(x),f(y)) \leq Cd_X(x,y)^p.$$
So what I am asking is if there is any obstruction to taking $p=1$ (maybe increasing the number of trees in the product if necessary).

Apologies if the question is foolish, I am not an expert on buildings.

Comment: I think taking $p=1$ is prevented by the Kleiner-Leeb result on quasi-isometric rigidity of Euclidean buildings: see Theorem 1.1.2 in http://www.math.nyu.edu/~bkleiner/symm.pdf

Comment: Prof. Valette: Thank you for the response. I don't see how Theorem 1.1.2 in Kleiner-Leeb answers my question, as the quasi-isometries considered in that theorem are assumed to be (coarsely) surjective, whereas I am only interested in an embedding result. (Or did I misunderstand? I reiterate my lack of expertise re: buildings.)

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the surjectivity issue. I leave my comment however, as a very partial contribution.

Comment: It's an open question whether $SL_{3}(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ (or equivalently its Euclidean building) has a quasi-isometric embedding into a product of trees (and more generally $SL_d(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ or $SL_d(\mathbf{R})$ for some/any $d\ge 3$).

Comment: Prof. de Cornulier: Thank you. So it appears that my slightly stronger question may be open as well (or false), but certainly that no proof is known. Do you know of a reference to read more about these specific examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem of existence/nonexistence of quasi-isometric embeddings $X\to Y$ between symmetric spaces and locally compact Euclidean buildings of rank $\ge 2$ is wide-open in the case when $rank(Y)> rank(X)$ (assuming, of course, that $dim(X)<dim(Y)$ in the setting of symmetric spaces). The most up-to date results and references can be found in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.0445v2.pdf) paper by Fisher and Whyte from last year.  For instance, it is not unreasonable to expect that each locally finite Euclidean building $X$ admits a QI embedding into the product of $n$ simplicial trees of valence $3$, where $n$ depends on $X$.

Comment: Prof. Kapovich: Thank you very much for the overview and the reference to the Fisher-Whyte paper, which I did not know. I have accepted this answer as a clear summary of the current state of knowledge: my question is open. I thank all the experts who took time to comment.